# Regex Combine E-Mail and Numbers but not link

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if a text has sensible information (for example e-mail adresses and numbers because a number can be a telephone number or customer id etc.).

I have a working pattern to detect e-mail:

```
/(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})/img
```

A working pattern to detect urls:

```
/(www|http:|https:)+[^\s]+[\w]/img
```

This is my current pattern for numbers:

```
/(| +|\+)(\d+){3,20}/img
```

But I want only detect numbers in some cases. They should not match when they are used in an url or when they are used in @mention of an username.

This is the text I test the patterns against:

> @HAMAPA @Waage1965
>
> www.telekomhilft.telekom.de/t5/Fragen-zur-Community/Community-Update-01-2018/m-p/3055244#M28054
>   der Ort der Schaltfläche ist fehlerhaft (gehört in das Register) bzw.
>   das Register ist fehlerhaft, weil diese Schaltfläche fehlt, das ist
>   nicht beabsichtigt, so wie es aussieht.test3@telekom.de
>   Denn215685553555 bezüglich PN-Register gibt es noch ein weiteres
>   Problem, das ich aber in einem anderen Beitrag gemeldet hatte. Und nur
>   weil die "Neue Nachrichten"-Schaltfläche am falschen Ort ist, ist die
>   dort überhaupt +490154555356 vorhanden, der Fehler des falschen Ortes 
>   gleicht somit derzeit ein Drittel eines anderen Fehlers aus. 0175
>   27557996
>
> 0175 12345678  001-541-754-3010 
>   +490154555356 04435/1111 12334546546565
>
> test2@gmx.net
>
> test1@t-online.de Bitte folge dem 04435/1111 Link zu meiner Meldung,
>   dort ist der Fehler beschrieben (inklusive zwei Bildern im Spoiler wie
>   es gerade fälschlicherweise ist und wie es eigentlich sein sollte an
>   der Stelle mit dem Register). Kannst ja mal selbst versuchen eine
>   vorhandene PN zu öffnen (z. B. aus deinen versendenen PNs) und dann
>   von dort auf eine PN der anderen Liste zu wechseln (z. B. auf
>   eingegangene PNs).
>   http://telekomhilft.telekom.de/t5/Fragen-zur-Community/Community-Update-01-2018/m-p/3055244#M28054
>   der Ort der Schaltfläche ist fehlerhaft (gehört in das Register) bzw.
>   das Register ist fehlerhaft, weil diese Schaltfläche fehlt, das ist
>   nicht beabsichtigt, so wie es aussieht.siegrun@telekom.de Denn
>   bezüglich PN-Register gibt es noch ein weiteres Problem, das ich aber
>   in einem anderen Beitrag gemeldet hatte. Und nur weil die "Neue
>   Nachrichten"-Schaltfläche am falschen Ort ist, ist die dort überhaupt
>   vorhanden, der Fehler des falschen Ortes  gleicht somit derzeit ein
>   Drittel eines anderen Fehlers aus.
>   https://telekomhilft.telekom.de/t5/Fragen-zur-Community/Community-Update-01-2018/m-p/3055244#M28054

In that example: I don't want that the numbers in the urls are matched and I don't want the number in the @mention of the username Waage1965 is matched.

And is it possible to combine the pattern in one pattern? What I want to achieve is that the user gets a warning if his text contains an e-mail adress or possibly a telephone number or customer id. But the warning should not appear if the numbers are just numbers in an url.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty nasty regex, but it works

```
/(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})|\+?[\d-]{9,18}/img
```

I pretty much added the OR (`|`) operator between your expressions, and modified the telephone's regex: `\+?[\d-]{9,18}`. You didn't define what you consider a phone number, so you can just tweak the numbers in the curly brackets.

A full test is [here](https://regex101.com/r/XFNaS5/1).

Comment: Thank you. But this regex also matches the urls. It should not match urls. I added the url pattern only to exclude numbers from a url. And one minor thing: This number is not matched in the example Denn215685553555 because it contains charactors. Is it possible to get a match in this case too?

Comment: @plutonium The regex in the answer wasn't matching the one in the link. I've updated the link

Comment: ah, okay. When I tweak the numbers in the curly brackets, the regex still matches numbers in the url or the username. Is there a way add a condition like "If number and url then no match"?

Comment: @plutonium You can't use a single regex to do this kind of conjunction, therefore I tried to work around this with the phone number's length